# Python: getting prices of smartphones from website

Tags: python, html, http, currency, digit-separator

I want to get the prices of smartphones from this website, http://tweakers.net. It's a Dutch site. The problem is that the prices are not collected from the website.

The textfile 'TweakersTelefoons.txt' contains 3 entries:

samsung-galaxy-s6-32gb-zwart

lg-nexus-5x-32gb-zwart

huawei-nexus-6p-32gb-zwart

I'm using python 2.7 and this is the code I used:

```
import urllib
import re

symbolfile = open("TweakersTelefoons.txt")
symbolslist = symbolfile.read()
symbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

for symbol in symbolslist:
    url = "http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/[^.]*/" +symbol+ ".html"
## http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/423541/samsung-galaxy-s6-32gb-zwart.html  is the original html

    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()

    regex = '<span itemprop="lowPrice">(.+?)</span>'
## <span itemprop="lowPrice">€ 471,95</span>  is what the original code looks like
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)

    print "the price of", symbol, "is ", price
```

Output:

the price of samsung-galaxy-s6-32gb-zwart is  []

the price of lg-nexus-5x-32gb-zwart is  []

the price of huawei-nexus-6p-32gb-zwart is  []

The prices are not shown
I tried using [^.] to get rid of the euro sign, but that didn't work.

Furthermore it might be that in Europe we use a "," instead of "." as a seperator for decimals.
Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a html parser, what are you trying to get from the site?

Comment: "http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/[^.]*/" does not do what you think. URL can not contain joker as "*" (or it is a very particular server configuration).

Comment: http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/423541/samsung-galaxy-s6-32gb-zwart.html   is the original url, is used [^.]* to replace th number 423541. I'm trying to get the prices of these smartphones.

Comment: I suggest using `for symbol in symbolslist` instead of your `while i < len(symbolslist)` and the `symbolslist[i]` code.

Comment: Yes, that looks better indeed. I will change it.

Comment: No matter what the original URL, you can't just pass a regex in a web request and expect the server to respond.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://tweakers.net/categorie/215/smartphones/producten/").content)

print [(p.a["href"], p.a.text) for p in soup.find_all("p",{"class":"price"})]
```

To get all the pages:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# base url to pass page number to 1-69 in this case
base_url = "http://tweakers.net/categorie/215/smartphones/producten/?page={}"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://tweakers.net/categorie/215/smartphones/producten/").content, "lxml")

# get and store all prices and phone links
data = {1: (p.a["href"], p.a.text) for p in soup.find_all("p", {'class': "price"})}

pag = soup.find("span", attrs={"class":"pageDistribution"}).find_all("a")

# last page number
mx_pg = max(int(a.text) for a in pag if a.text.isdigit())

# get all the pages from the second to  mx_pg 
for i in range(2, mx_pg + 1):
    req = requests.get(base_url.format(i))
    print req
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)
    data[i] = [(p.a["href"], p.a.text) for p in soup.find_all("p",{"class":"price"})]
```

You will need both [requests](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=requests%20python), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). The dict has the links to each phones page that you can visit if you want to scrape more data.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PyScripter\PyScripter\MyScripts\WebScrapers\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests

Comment: @JohanVerburg, you need to install, you can do it with pip, `pip install requests` and do the same for bs4

Comment: i installed both requests and BeautifulSoup. I ran code above and het the following:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module2>", line 18, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 156, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: Just remove the lxml as I have now, I would recommend install lxml though if you plan on doing a lot of scraping

Comment: When I remove "lxml" I get the following results:                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PyScripter\PyScripter\MyScripts\WebScrapers\test2.py", line 23, in <module>
    pag = soup.find("span", attrs={"class":"pageDistribution"}).find_all("a")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: I get 68 `<Response [200]>` and a dict full of prices and links from 1-69 using the default parser and lxml.  You can try installing another parser and specifying that http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: I don't get it, i installed different parsers like "html5lib", "lxml" or even "html.parser" but keep getting the same error like mentioned above. I'll give it another go tomorrow at work.

Comment: I cannot think of any reason as I used the big standard html.parser and lxml with no issue although when windows is involved anything is possible.

Comment: At work I get this error:      ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='tweakers.net', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /categorie/215/smartphones/producten/ (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)                                                                                                           Any ideas?

Comment: @JohanVerburg, add this to the code `import httplib` and 
`httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1`, that will give us some debug output, you are not behind a proxy by any chance?

Comment: I added the code you suggested but no additional output was given. Only the same error. I don't know if I am behind a proxy. I am working on a virtual machine at work.

Comment: The error is related to your network more than python, can you access using curl?

Comment: Yeah I think it has to do with the network. I ll leave it at that for now using python. I will be looking into javascript next since that is the way colleagues have build scrapers. Thank you for the help though Padraic.

Comment: No worries,  I think whatever you use you will need to sort out the network issue, I would also recommend looking at scrapy is you want to build proper scrapers http://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you are expecting a web server to resolve a wildcard within a URL with `"http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/[^.]*/` and you are not checking the returned code which I suspect is 404.

You need to either identify the product ID if that is fixed or post a search request using the forms post method.